# Get IdentityDbContext during ValidateClientAuthentication in my custom OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, owin, asp.net-identity-2

I am building a web.api service which uses token for authorization. 
I've followed the guidelines used by Dominick Baier in his blog [here](http://leastprivilege.com/2013/11/13/embedding-a-simple-usernamepassword-authorization-server-in-web-api-v2/).

Today I've updated all the packages for Owin, Entity Framework and ASP.NET web.api and I've found out that lots of things have changed.

I've found a few articles on the web (apparently there no documentation about these topics) and started to convert my web.api service.

This [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/03/20/test-announcing-rtm-of-asp-net-identity-2-0-0.aspx) about the new ASP.NET Identity 2.0.0 helped me to convert pretty much everything but now I am stuck on a simple stupid matter.

I've managed to create my customer **ApplicationUserManager** and **ApplicationDbContext** as suggested in the blog.

In my **Startup** I've associated my 2 object with the Owin Context:

```
app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationDatabaseContext>(ApplicationDatabaseContext.Create);
app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
```

I have defined a custom **OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider** cause I want to use **Bearer Authentication**:

```
var OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
{
    AllowInsecureHttp = true,
    TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/oauth/Token"),
    AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(8),
    Provider = new MyAuthorizationServerProvider(),
    RefreshTokenProvider = new MyRefreshTokenProvider(DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(8))
};
```

In my **MyAuthorizationServerProvider** I have overidden **ValidateClientAuthentication** cause I want to check client credentials.

Everything seems to work fine and I can get my **IAuthenticationManager** from **OwinContext** :

```
public override async Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
{
    string clientId = string.Empty;
    string clientSecret = string.Empty;

    if (context.TryGetBasicCredentials(out clientId, out clientSecret))
    {
        IAuthenticationManager manager = context.OwinContext.Authentication;
        ...
        ...
    }
}
```

but I don't seem to be able to get my **ApplicationDbContext**.
The only way I can achieve this is using the key which I've found going through the variables registered:

```
var dbContext = context.OwinContext.Get<ApplicationDbContext>("AspNet.Identity.Owin:OwinWebApiSecurity.Services.ApplicationDatabaseContext, OwinWebApiSecurity, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null");
```

I was wondering if there a simpler way to achieve the same thing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apparently I have to import **Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin** namespace to have access to those extension methods.

```
ApplicationDbContext dbContext = context.OwinContext.Get<ApplicationDbContext>();
ApplicationUserManager userManager = context.OwinContext.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
```